# Is this set Reflexive, Symmetric or Transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the set:
$$R = \{(x,y)\;|\;x\times y \leq 2015 \;\;\text{and}\;\; x,y \subset \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}\}$$

Would this set be just symmetric as I think? Or am I misunderstanding set relations?

Comment: why do you think this is not transitive?

Comment: I think you're understanding set relations properly. You should give a specific counterexample $x$ showing $R$ is not reflexive because not $xRx$, and similarly $x,y,z$ showing it's not transitive.

Comment: @BrianO $x=100, y=20, z=50$ would be suitable?

Comment: @BrianO and I've given the point that $x$ or $y$ could be $2015$ but you couldn't have the reflex as $(2015, 2015)$ wouldn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: Sure, both counterexamples work. Another showing non-transitivity is $(1215,1)$ and $(1,1215)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of all listed properties, this $R$ (considered as a binary relation on $\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$, I suppose) is only symmetric (which it is because multiplication is commutative). It is not reflexive because $(45,45)\notin R$.
It is not transitive, for example because $(1000,2)\in R$ and $(2,100)\in R$, but $(1000,100)\notin R$.